# How to specify language, location and city with facebook graph api

Tags: facebook-graph-api, actionscript-3, facebook-as3-api

I am using FacebookGraphAPIDesktop.swc api to create unpublished post.

How can I assign language, location and city parameter with it?

Currently I am creating it like below :-

```
var params:Object = new Object();               
params.access_token = PhotoToken;
params.published = 0;                           
params.message = "Test unpublished post";                                               
FacebookDesktop.api("/" + PageID +"/feed", StatusPosted, params,"POST");
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution and posting here if anyone needs it :-

We need to pass it as a json string :-

```
var targeting:String = "{'countries':['US','IN']}";

_params.access_token = token;
_params.published = 0;      
_params.message = "This is status message 5";                   
_params.targeting = targeting;                  
FacebookDesktop.api("/202387076493582/feed", messagePosted1, _params,"POST");
```